# How can I restrict ports to a host created by docker-machine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I want to create a database machine that only accepts connections to 5432 from certain IPs. The other machines I want to allow to connect to this database machine are not running docker. I've deployed a host using `docker-machine` on digital ocean using this docker-compose file:

```
postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /tmp/postgrescont:/tmp
  volumes_from:
    - data
  env_file: .dbenv
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

data:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: "true"
```

And tried to allow only traffic from another certain host like this:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -s <ip address of certain other host> -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -j DROP # deny other traffic
```

But, for some reason, I can still connect from unwanted hosts. Any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I was able to restrict port 5432 to a certain IP:

```
iptables -I DOCKER 1 -p tcp ! -s <other_host_ip_allowed> --dport 5432 -j DROP
```

I inserted the rule to be the 1st rule of the DOCKER chain and to drop any other IP that is not the one I specify.

Comment: after searching for the same topic, i have found [this blog posting](http://rudijs.github.io/2015-07/docker-restricting-container-access-with-iptables/) which explains very well with a ready to use bash script

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what Docker recommends.

> Docker’s forward rules permit all external source IPs by default. To allow only a specific IP or network to access the containers, insert a negated rule at the top of the DOCKER filter chain. For example, to restrict external access such that only source IP 8.8.8.8 can access the containers, the following rule could be added:
>
> $ iptables -I DOCKER -i ext_if ! -s 8.8.8.8 -j DROP

[Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/)